# Are Java array accesses one operation for multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, memory, multidimensional-array, compilation

I was considering the following Java code, and it got me thinking about how arrays actually work in Java.

```
int[][] arr = ...
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = ...
    }
}
```

I typically think of a 2D array as an array of arrays, so I would think that `arr[i][j]` would require two array accesses: one to get the array stored at `arr[i]`, and another to get the jth element from it.  However, I know that in C, the [] notation is more a syntactic sugar that does pointer arithmetic, so `arr[i][j]` would require one array access there.

How does this work in Java?  Does accessing into an element in a multi-dimensional array require constant time?  Or if I have an n-dimensional array, does Java does n array accesses?  Or does something different happen?

I tried writing some code to access arrays with an increasing number of dimensions, but I wasn't sure if doing this iteratively in a loop would somehow change how the compiler interprets it, so I tried hard coding this up to 10 dimensions and I didn't see any difference in how long it took to write to an element in the arrays.  I can't imagine ever needing an array with more than a few dimensions, but I'm still interested in this in the abstract sense of how this scales with the number of dimensions of the array.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/EfKqM3oc5